# Finding the Program that Calls a Specific DLL/method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DLL in Prod across dozens of programs. There is a method that is failing and writing to our event log with a non-specific error. We have a fix for the issue, but that would require a new DLL version and deploying to all of our applications that use that DLL. Additionally, it would require weeks of testing.

Searching source code has been unsuccessful so far because the method has a common name. How can I find the one program calling the method failing in the DLL?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Use ILSpy to analyze all your executables and look for the type containing the method and then look for places where the specific method is invoked. After the code is compiled, its common name doesn't matter - the call is made to a specific member of a specific type. If this member is used in multiple places, you'll still have to figure out which one is giving you too little information.

Comment: Am I to understand from this question that your library (in all of its instances) is logging to **one central log**, i.e. this log contains all messages from all usages of this library? Because if so, that seems like a really bad idea (exactly because of the problem you're now faced with) that I would tackle head on, and IMO the question is pretty much an XY problem in that case.

Comment: can you provide more information are you testing in debugging mode or in production , what are you using for your logging , and please add your code

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching the source code and failing because the name is common, it sounds like you're doing a full-text search. If you are using Visual Studio, do the following:

- Find any place the method is referenced in your code and place the cursor there.
- Hit F12 to open the method (source code if the DLL project is part of the solution, otherwise in the object browser. It doesn't matter).
- Right-click the method name (in source code or the object browser) and pick Find All References.

If you have multiple solutions, you'll need to repeat once for each solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ReSharper for Visual Studio, use Find Usages(Alt +F7) to see where that method is called.

If you have multiples solutions, use Total Commander text search to find all usages.

Comment: This only works in cases where all the applications are in the same solution. It doesn't apply for applications with their own solution file.